# Change <Apex:Page> attributes via javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

How can I change the language attribute on the  tag to a different value via javascript on page load ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `apex:...` tags is to generate HTML on the server-side that is then consumed by the browser on the client-side. As JavaScript is executing on the client-side where the tags no longer directly exist you need to take a different approach e.g. a page parameter that the Apex controller makes available to the Visualforce.